# Responsive form with different background

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
h2{
    font-weight: 700;
}
h4{
    color:#F13F6C
}
.signup-section{
    padding-top: 2rem;
}
form{
    padding-top:10rem;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){/*Mac*/
.background-form{
    height: 60em;
    width: auto;
    background: url("https://www.apple.com/v/macbook-air/k/images/specs/mba_router__c00eqnbbyuy6_large_2x.png") center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: -12rem;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px){
    .contatti{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
  @media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 500px){/*Ipad*/
  .background-form{
      height: 60em;
      width: auto;
      background: url("https://miopc.it/90275-large_default/apple-ipad-pro-129-con-chip-m1-quinta-gen-wi-fi-256gb-grigio-siderale.jpg") center center;
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center 0px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin-bottom: -12rem;
      }
  }
@media (max-width: 500px){/*Iphone*/
.background-form{
    height: 70em;
    width: auto;
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/IPhone_11_Pro_Midnight_Green.svg/1200px-IPhone_11_Pro_Midnight_Green.svg.png") center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: -35rem;
    }
}
.contatti{
    padding-top: 10rem;
}

#contacts .form-control{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 0;
}
#contacts .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: white
        }
#contacts .form-control:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: rgba(147, 147, 147, 1.00);
        }
#contacts .form-control:focus{
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 rgb(249,249,249);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

textarea{
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
<link href="stile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body><div id="contacts">
    <!-- SINGUP -->
    <section id="signup" class="signup-section">
    
        <div class="background-form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="contatti col-4 d-flex flex-column text-center offset-2 text-white mt-5">
            <h3>Contacts</h3>
                    <h5 style="color: #0000c5; font-weight: 400;">Info</h5>
                    <p>email@gmail.com<br>123456789<br><br></p>
                    <h5 style="color: #0000c5; font-weight: 400;">Address</h5>
                    <p>abcdefghijklm0<br>
                    abababababababab<br> Mexico
                    </p>
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 d-flex flex-column mt-5 col-xl-5">
              <form class="invia text-white text-left">
                  <fieldset>
                  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
   <div class="form-floating">
   <label for="nome">Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control text-white" id="nome" placeholder="" required>
   </div>
   </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
                          <div class="form-floating">
                          <label for="cognome">Surname</label>
                              <input type="text"  name="cognome" class="form-control text-white" id="cognome" placeholder="" required>
                          </div>
                      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-8">
   <div class="form-floating">
   <label for="nome">mail</label>
   <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control text-white" id="email" placeholder="" required>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
         <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-8">            
   <div class="form-fluid">
   <label for="nome">Text</label>
   <textarea class="form-control text-white" name="messaggio" placeholder="" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 80px" required></textarea>
       <div class="mx-auto mt-4 col-xl-7">
         <button class="fill btn-block " type="submit">Send</button>
</div>
       </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section> 
        

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi everyone, I have a problem on a form that has to adapt to the different responsive modes (the background will change according to the device in which the form will be viewed). I want to use only one form, without having to create several, I'm using Bootstrap, but when I can adapt it to the responsive version on ipad or iphone, then it no longer works on Mac. Can you help me solve it? (PS. Only on the Mac appears the writing on the sides with the info, on the responsive it disappears and it works, on CodePen I don't understand why it doesn't read it, you can not even consider it that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ella I cannot find any issue with your CSS.
According to the HTML you have posted it does not contain your custom CSS file. can you check it by adding

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

to your **head** tag.

Comment: Yes I had missed the link.